# How to pass the 2D array from one class to another in Tkinter?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to write my first app using Tkinter. I can't understand at all how it is possible to pass the data on variables in the 2D array (entered by user) from one class to another. Tried to change something, but nothing turned out. I will be very grateful for any help or advice.

```
from Tkinter import *

date_index = [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
product_name = ['product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3', 'product 4', 'product 5']

class main: 
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('revenue calc')

        Button(self.master, text = 'quantity', command=self.q_button).pack()
        Button(self.master, text = 'prices', command=self.p_button).pack()

        self.master.mainloop()

    def q_button(self):
        q_child(self.master)

    def p_button(self):
        p_child(self.master)

class q_child:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.slave = Toplevel(master)
        self.slave.title('quantity')

        self.corner_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.corner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.left_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.left_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.head_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.head_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.button_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=2, column=1)


        for i in range(len(product_name)):
            self.testlabel = Label(self.left_frame, text = product_name[i])
            self.testlabel.grid(row=i, column=0)

        for j in range(len(date_index)):
            self.testlabel1 = Label(self.head_frame, width = 5, text = date_index[j])
            self.testlabel1.grid(row=0, column=j)

        self.q0 = []

        for j in range(len(date_index)):
            self.q0.append([])
            for i in range(len(product_name)):
                self.q0[j].append(Entry(self.slave, width = 5, text=""))
                self.q0[j][i].grid(row=j, column=i, in_ = self.main_frame)

        self.save_q_button = Button(self.button_frame, text = 'save', command = self.save_q_data)
        self.save_q_button.pack()

    def save_q_data(self):
        self.q = []

        for j in range(len(date_index)):
            self.q.append([])
            for i in range(len(product_name)):  
                self.q[j].append(float(self.q0[j][i].get()))

class p_child:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.slave = Toplevel(master)
        self.slave.title('prices')

        self.corner_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.corner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.left_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.left_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.head_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.head_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.button_frame = Frame(self.slave)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=2, column=1)


        for i in range(len(product_name)):
            self.testlabel = Label(self.left_frame, text = product_name[i])
            self.testlabel.grid(row=i, column=0)

        for j in range(len(date_index)):
            self.testlabel1 = Label(self.head_frame, width = 5, text = date_index[j])
            self.testlabel1.grid(row=0, column=j)

        self.p0 = []

        for j in range(len(date_index)):
            self.p0.append([])
            for i in range(len(product_name)):
                self.p0[j].append(Entry(self.slave, width = 5, text=""))
                self.p0[j][i].grid(row=j, column=i, in_ = self.main_frame)

        self.save_p_button = Button(self.button_frame, text = 'save', command = self.save_p_data)
        self.save_p_button.pack()

    def save_p_data(self):
        self.rev = []
        self.revall = []
        self.p = []

        for j in range(len(date_index)):
            self.rev.append([])
            self.p.append([])
            self.s = 0
            for i in range(len(product_name)):  
                self.p[j].append(float(self.p0[j][i].get()))
                self.rev[j].append(self.p[j][i]*q[j][i]) # NameError: global name 'q' is not defined
                self.s += self.rev[j][i]
            self.revall.append(self.s)  

root = Tk()
main(root)
```

Comment: Post your errors/outputs.

Comment: NameError: global name 'q' is not defined. But when I try to define it in main class, it 'destroys' all inputs from childs.

Comment: Also I can add that expected outputs are following. For q_child - 2D array: q = [[...q1i...][...q2i...]...]. For p_child: p = [[...p1i...][...p2i...]...], rev = [[...q1ip1i...][...q2ip2i...]...]. There is no problem with first and second. The last produces error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below a simplified version of your code which shows how to pass data (in this case the text of a single Entry box) from your `TopLevel()` window back to your main window.

Basically, in your `q_child` class, you store the data you want to return in an attribute called, for example, `self.data`, so that when you return to the main class, you can access it by calling `q.data`.

You can even store this data in the main window's `master` attribute under a name like `q_data`, so that it can be accessed in the `p_child` class, through `master.q_data`

```
import Tkinter as tk

class main: 
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.q_data = "No data entered"
        tk.Button(self.master, text='quantity', command=self.q_button).pack()
        tk.Button(self.master, text='prices', command=self.p_button).pack()
        self.master.mainloop()

    def q_button(self):
        # Create a TopLevel window to get user input
        q = q_child(self.master)
        # Wait for the user to close the TopLevel window
        self.master.wait_window(q.slave)
        # Store the data input by the user in the main window's "master" attribute
        self.master.q_data = q.data

    def p_button(self):
        # Create a TopLevel window to use the user input data
        p = p_child(self.master)
        # Wait for the user to close the TopLevel window
        self.master.wait_window(p.slave)

class q_child:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Create a TopLevel window, and grab focus
        self.slave = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.slave.grab_set()

        # Add an Entry box and a button
        self.q_entry = tk.Entry(self.slave, text="")
        self.q_entry.pack()
        tk.Button(self.slave, text='save', command=self.save_q_data).pack()

        # Initialize the data to be returned
        self.data = "No data entered"

    def save_q_data(self):
        # Update the data to be returned with the Entry box content
        self.data = self.q_entry.get()
        # Close the TopLevel window
        self.slave.destroy()

class p_child:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Create a TopLevel window, and grab focus
        self.slave = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.slave.grab_set()

        # Retrieve the user-input data from the "master"
        q_data = master.q_data
        # Show the data on a label
        tk.Label(self.slave, text=q_data).pack()
        # Add a button to go back
        tk.Button(self.slave, text='back', command=self.slave.destroy).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
main(root)
```

**Important**: `self.master.wait_window(q.slave)` ensures that the main class waits for the TopLevel window to be closed before continuing to run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still don't understand how one can use q.data in p_child class. When I try to do this the same mistake occurs: "NameError: global name 'q' is not defined". How can I avoid this?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to access the data from the q window in the p window, by storing it in their common `master`.